# C++ and C# IoT - C++ project access C# DLLs in another project

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, iot

I am trying to make a Windows IoT app in C++ where I can use C# code as well.

I first created a solution with a Visual C++ Blank Windows IoT Core Console Application. Here is the code in the entry point:

```
// EnterPoint.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>

#include "pch.h"

#using <MainLogic.dll>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int result = MainLogic::StartupTask::Start();
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Then I created another project in the same solution named MainLogic, this time a Visual C# Class Library (Portable) using .NET Framework 6 and the default targets as well as Windows Phone 8.1. Here is the code in the C# file I made:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MainLogic
{
    public class StartupTask
    {
        public static int Start()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I built the C# project, and added `..\MainLogic\bin\Debug` to the Reference Directories and C/C++ -> Additional #using Directories of the C++ project.

When I ran this on a Local Windows Debugger with an x86 architecture, it gave an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MainLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at main(Int32 argc, SByte** argv)
   at _mainCRTStartup()
```

in the resulting command prompt window. It prompted me to break, and I did. That window said this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x75613E28 (KernelBase.dll) in PythonInCSharpInCPP.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80070002, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x72D60000).
```

I went to the last address (0x72D60000), and somewhere around it was the text "This program cannot be run in DOS mode".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489924/can-you-use-c-dlls-in-c-sharp-code-in-a-uwp/33490707?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

You need at add the C# project as a dependency in the C++ one.  Then when you build the C# DLL will be copied to the C++ output directory.

The 0x72D60000 address is the base address the DLL was loaded at.  Every windows program starts with a stub that says it can't be run in DOS mode, for use back in the days when MS-DOS was still being run along with windows.  That part is skipped when run under Windows.

Comment: I checked MainLogic in Project -> Project Dependencies, but the error sill came up.