# Can you use C++ DLLs in C# code in a UWP?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, uwp

I wrote a C++ Class Library in Visual Studio that just defines a function that invokes some Python:

```
#pragma once

#include <Python.h>

extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport)
void python()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("2 + 2");
}
```

I made another project in the same solution that was a C# Blank Universal app. I tried to reference the DLL generated from the previous project I mentioned:

```
using System;
...

namespace StartupApp
{
    ...
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        private const string CPPPythonInterfaceDLL = @"pathtodll";

        [DllImport(CPPPythonInterfaceDLL, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void python();

        public static void Python()
        {
            python();
        }
        ...
        public App()
        {
            ...

            Python();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

The app is in a Release configuration.

Whenever I try to run the app on my Local Machine, it always gives an error:

```
The program '[2272] StartupApp.exe' has exited with code -1073741790 (0xc0000022).
Activation of the Windows Store app 'ab6a8ef2-1fa8-4cc7-b7b3-fb7420af7dc3_7dk3a6v9mg4g6!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
```

So my question is this: can I reference a C++ class library from a C# UWP project? Or does the security on UWP apps not allow this?

Or is it because of Python.h?

EDIT:

I built the project with a DLL project and a Runtime Component that wrapped it, and now I have this error:

An exception of type 'System

```
'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in StartupApp.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'pathtodll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I added a user to the DLL with the object name "Everyone" (I am not sure how else to give everyone permissions) but the error still comes up.

Comment: Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.  Did you try to enable native debugging?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, UWP can't consume a legacy C++ dll just by DLLImport.

If you want to expose legacy c++ functions to C#, the first suggestion is to wrap that C++ logic using a WinRT component. Then you can reference this component in UWP application by following steps: adding it to the project, open the files' properties in the Solution Explorer window, and mark them as content to be included in the app package. [This post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx) would be helpful. [This one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisbarker/archive/2014/10/08/consuming-a-c-library-project-from-a-windows-phone-store-app.aspx) provides more detailed steps.

If you want to PInvoke the dll, you can follow these steps (You can refer to this [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4440c2d-9386-4df5-9419-6b016cf8b345/uwp-native-pinvoke-dll-compiled-with-mingw?forum=wpdevelop)):

1. Add win32 dll into your UWP project making sure to set its type as 'content'
2. Then in the proper cs file, using DllImport to PInvoke the dll.

There is one more thing: You need to make sure your Python dll is not using prohibited APIs in WinRT. You can check this by using /ZW compile option for the dll.

Comment: I used the second article. Which DLL do I need to DllImport, the one in the DLL Universal project, or the one in the Runtime Component. And the same for the /ZW: the DLL or the Runtime Component project (please excuse my questions, I am not very familiar with .NET).

Comment: I updated the post with PInvoke usage. You'd better read the first post, too. It explains different ways to port legacy C++ dll to UWP.

Comment: Please try these steps to make sure the DLL is added correctly: Add the DLL to the project, open the DLL's properties in the Solution Explorer window, and mark them as content to be included in the app package.

Comment: I "Add"ed an "Existing Item" to the project (the item - the Win32 Class Library DLL- being in a different directory). Then, in properties, I chose "Content" in "Advanced" -> "Build Actions". For "Copy to Output Directory", I selected "Do not copy". In my C#, I use the full path to the DLL. The C# code DllImport's the DLL and calls it (without specifying any namespace before it).

Comment: Access Denied suggests that your DLL is not included in the app package. Make sure the binary is included in the project and marked as content, then double check it ends up in the Appx after building. The app cannot read or load arbitrary DLLs from other locations. And you also need to make sure the API you invoke is allowed for UWP and Windows Runtime apps. This could be checked by compiling the DLL with /ZW. And this link is helpful to find compatible APIs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx

Comment: How do you do this? In Package.appxmanifest, I cannot find a tab that lists references. It is a "Dependency" in the XML?

Comment: You can find a sample for DLLImport in this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4440c2d-9386-4df5-9419-6b016cf8b345/uwp-native-pinvoke-dll-compiled-with-mingw?forum=wpdevelop. I have tried it myself, and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much the second post helped me :) @Fangfang Wu - MSFT

Comment: Some more clues: If your DLL depends on others that are not present, LoadPackagedLibrary will fail with an error 126 (ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This may confuse you, because it does find your DLL, but not its dependencies. Copy your DLL to the root of your project, add them to the project (add existing element) and mark that they are copied. The path that you put in LoadPackagedLibrary is the name of your DLL.