# How to import C++ Legacy DLL in C# UWP application without Windows Runtime Component

Tags: c#, uwp, dllimport

We have a requirement to import a C++ legacy dll inside C# UWP application and access the methods inside the c++ classes. We don't have the source code with us, So not able to do with the Windows Run time component.

Please let me know how can I import the c++ dll inside the Visual C# universal windows application.

I am able to add the dll as a reference in visual C++ application, But not able to do it in visual C# uwp application. I have tried the dllimport but it is throwing dll not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, UWP can't import a legacy C++ dll just by DLLImport.

If you want to import legacy c++ functions to C#, the first suggestion is to wrap that C++ logic using a WinRT component.

And if you want to PInvoke the dll, you can follow these steps (You can refer to this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4440c2d-9386-4df5-9419-6b016cf8b345/uwp-native-pinvoke-dll-compiled-with-mingw?forum=wpdevelop)):​ First, add dll into your UWP project making sure to set its type as '**content**'​. Then in the proper cs file, using DllImport to PInvoke the dll.​

In addition, you need to make sure your dll is not using prohibited APIs in WinRT. You can check this by using /ZW compile option for the dll. There is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489924/can-you-use-c-dlls-in-c-sharp-code-in-a-uwp), you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped. I have used the Dll Import instead of Win RT wrapper. But while accessing the  method inside the dll , I am getting this error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: When I tested it, it worked well. Can you provide more information about how you access the method and the definition in C++ header file. In addition, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced?