# How to add dll file into a UWP Project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, uwp, pdfium

I'm building a UWP Viewer for the Pdfium library(pdfium.dll). pdfium.dll is a c++ class library.
In my Visual Studio Solution, I have two UWP projects.
First Project(PdfiumViewer) is a UWP Class Library which imports functions from pdfium.dll and creates user controls.
Eg:

```
[DllImport("pdfium.dll")]
public static extern void FPDF_AddRef();
```

The second project(PdfiumViewer.Demo) is a UWP Blank App and I referenced the first project here So that I can use its user controls in this project. I included pdfium.dll into the bin folder of my second project. But when I run the program, I get an exception saying "Unable to load pdfium.dll".

There is an existing similar Viewers developed for .Net Windows Forms and WPF apps.

I tried to add pdfium.dll as a reference by right-clicking reference -> "Add reference". In all of these cases(.Net WinForm, .Net WPF, UWP), adding it gave me an error. (ERROR :  A reference to ....\pdfium.dll could not be added. please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component)

I added the pdfium.dll into .Net WinForm and .Net WPF in a similar way(to the bin folder) and run them. Both types of application viewers worked fine.

**My Question:** **Since UWP apps run in a sandbox, Is there a special location to add this dll(pdfium.dll)?**

Note: I tried to add the file in different locations. (inside APPX folder, inside bin\Debug folder, inside bin\Debug\x64, etc)

Comment: this might be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019

Comment: I found out that pdfium.dll is needed to be in APPX/x64 folder. Yet I get an exception saying that "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load pdfium.dll or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Please copy your dll to the project folder and set the type as content.

Comment: I debug the code using breakpoints and found out that LoadLibrary(path) returned IntPtr.Zero. File.Exists(path) returned true. Does anyone familiar with pdfium library? Is it possible to use that DLL in a UWP environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When adding the dll to the VS UWP Project, follow the below steps.

First, check the dll using a dependency checker and find out whether the dll is needing additional dependencies.( Such as any other dlls)

Then,
(1). Right-click the project -> "Add" -> "Add existing item" -> Select the dll -> Choose **"Add as Link"** Button from the arrowhead in Add button. 
(2). After adding the dll, Change the properties as "Content" and "Copy if newer".

Answer (score 2):

> How to add dll file into a UWP Project

Derive from this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33490707/7254781), you need copy your dll to the project folder and set the  type as **content**. Then in the proper cs file, using DllImport to PInvoke the dll.

Comment: Can't add the dll into the project via references, hence can't set the type as **content** . Even if add as existing item and set as **content**, LoadLibrary(path) or LoadPackagedLibrary(path) return IntPtr.Zero.

Comment: **Edit for above comment**   Can't add the dll into the project via references(won't allow from VS), hence can't set the type as **content**. Even if add as existing item and set as **content**, LoadLibrary(path) or LoadPackagedLibrary(path) return IntPtr.Zero. Try to wrap around a UWP WinRT Component, but as I understood, source code is needed as a VS project(At least as .Net Class Library). Pdfium source code use GN and ninja build system and the project don't come as VS Project   Any Suggestions? Or Need more clarifications?

Comment: You could drag the dll file then drop it into project. Can't do it ?

Comment: I added that way too. The same thing happened. LoadLibrary(path) or LoadPackagedLibrary(path) return IntPtr.Zero.