# Call GetDiskFreeSpaceExA from UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, kernel32

I am working on a UWP app (C#, Visual Studio 2019) and I want to find out the total, free for user and free space of C:. In order to do this, I want to call GetDiskFreeSpaceExA (about GetDiskFreeSpaceExA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdiskfreespaceexa).

I tried the following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(string path,
                                        out ulong freeBytesForUser,
                                        out ulong totalNumberOfBytes,
                                        out ulong totalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Then, I call GetDiskFreeSpaceExA:

```
ulong freeUser;
ulong total;
ulong free;
string pathC= @"C:\"; // also tried with "C:\\" and @"C:\\"
bool success =  GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(pathC,
                                    out freeUser,
                                    out total,
                                    out free);

if(success)
{
     // ...
}
```

*success* is always false. Why? How can I find out the space on C: from UWP? I know that there are some C# methods, but I want DLLs.

Thank you!

Comment: Only works on Windows.  There are libraries that will allow on MAC.   Is project x64 or x32.

Comment: It is a Windows application. Sorry for not mentioning this!

Comment: Importing DLLs into an UWP app is not straightforward, so maybe your problem is connected to the way you're importing the DLL. Take a look at this answer; it sheds some light onto importing DLLs in an UWP app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33490707/1393899

Comment: "*If the function fails, the return value is zero (0). **To get extended error information, call GetLastError**.*"

Comment: Why not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace?view=net-5.0 ?

Comment: It throws exception. Cannot access the drive information. Using the DLL I can access only the information about C drive, which is better than nothing. Is there any way to access the drive information from UWP using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace?view=net-5.0 ? Thank  you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability in `Package.appxmanifest`.
This is a restricted capability. Access is configurable in ****Settings** > Privacy > File system.**

Please refer to the following code.

Package.appxmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"   

 xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
……
 <Capabilities>
   <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />   
 </Capabilities>
```

Code behind:

```
public async void test()
    {

        const String k_freeSpace = "System.FreeSpace";
        const String k_totalSpace = "System.Capacity";

        try
            {
               
                StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\");
                var props = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { k_freeSpace, k_totalSpace });
                Debug.WriteLine("FreeSpace: " + (UInt64)props[k_freeSpace]);
                Debug.WriteLine("Capacity:  " + (UInt64)props[k_totalSpace]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Couldn't get info for drive C."));
            }
        
    }
```